# Casting a buffer with larger size structure

Tags: c++, casting

I am casting a data buffer to large size structure pointer. Will it cause any issue? I tried the codes below on Visual Studio, no warning or error is found.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
    char var1;
    char var2;
    long var3;
};
void function(char* data);

int main (void)
{
    char data[5] = {1, 0, 0, 3, 4};
    function(data);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void function(char* data)
{
    test* pTest = reinterpret_cast<test*>(data); // casting
    printf("%x\n", pTest->var1);
    printf("%x\n", pTest->var2);
    printf("%x\n", pTest->var3);
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's a problem that you are *doing this* in the first place. The byte size of `data` is 5, but the byte size of `struct test` is at least 6, possibly 8 according to your compiler's padding behaviour. So the reinterpreted data will read past the end of data into some unknown memory region, when you access `var3`. This should cause a Segmentation Fault at runtime (but may not, depending on how `malloc()` works on your system).  TL;DR; if this happens to work for you, it's merely luck. for this to become sensible code, `sizeof(data)` must be >= `sizeof(test)`.

Comment: Any way you look at this it is just a bad idea.

Comment: This might appear to work and will may even run as you expect when you're testing it, but it has the potential to cause incorrect data and crashes at random times.  No good can come from this.

Comment: Anyone comment on the consequences should only elements in the structure within the allocated memory be accessed, other than alignment issues which apply in any case?

Comment: The question is extracted from part of my communication protocol design. Based on different header ID, the design will go thru switch case, casting to different structure.

I am exploring the impact of the embedded system if casting to incorrect length. I am using Win EA 7.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted if it solves your problem. It will help these searching for answer to your problem later.

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand, how memory management works. You allocated the array `data` statically, so it will be put on the stack (which holds frames with local variables of called functions). The stack is allocated statically for every process (that means, through processes lifetime it has constant size).

Since now, stack looks more-less like this:

```
data[1, 0, 0, 3, 4]
```

Now you called the function `function`. New frame was put on the stack, so it looks more-less like this:

```
data[1, 0, 0, 3, 4] | return-pointer[a b c d] pTest [e f a b]
(main data)           (function data)
```

Now, you cast data to your type, which size is at least 6 bytes (let's assume that, it may take 8 or more bytes, depending on class contents alignment). So you try to access these bytes:

```
data[1, 0, 0, 3, 4] | return-pointer[a b c d] pTest [e f a b]
(main data)           (function data)
     *  *  *  *  *                   *
```

(Please note, that my visualization of stack is simplified, it's possible, that there are more data left after calling the function).

All of the memory you access during later printf's belongs to your application, so OS raises no access violation errors. You read the data, so you don't damage anything. But now suppose, that you'll write something to `pTest->var3`. These bytes will be overwritten:

```
data[1, 0, 0, 3, 4] | return-pointer[a b c d] pTest [e f a b]
(main data)           (function data)
     *  *  #  #  #                   #
```

And now look, you just damaged the return-pointer - it is mostly likely, that your program will now crash while trying to exit `function` and return to `main`.

Generally it is *strongly* advised to cast only compatible data types (of equal sizes). Compiler often has no way of knowing, if your cast is valid (especially, if you cast pointers to `void *` on the way). So you should take great care about making casts in your programs.

Answer (score 0):

such kind of casting is very dangerous (in other words, you say to compiler - "I know that I do"), so in this case you have to check correctness such castings youself.

Answer (score 0):

The `reinterpret_cast<xxx>(yyy)` is telling the compiler "Trust me, I know what I'm doing here". Which means you have to be absolutely sure, yourself, that what you are doing is correct.

In this particular case, you are causing undefined behaviour, because your struct is larger than the data you passed in, which is definitely not and never a good thing - it may cause almost anything to happen (and that includes "something that resembles what you expect") - and worse, it may vary depending on what options used when compiling, so it may well appear to work in debug mode, and then fall over when you compile in release mode. At the very least `var3` will have some undefined content, based on the fact that at least part, of not all of `var3` is outside of your defined data. This depends on the size and aligmnent for a `long`. In Windows, this is 4 bytes and aligned to four bytes. So there is a space of 2 bytes between your two char fields and the `long` data.

However, it is possible to use this sort of scheme if you KNOW what you are doing, and you don't access `var3` in the `function` code.

Finally, if this is part of a comms protocol, it probably needs to be looked at from a "what padding is/needs to be added" perspective. If the protocol requires certain spacing, this needs to be dealt with correctly - at the same time, the processor may have strict requirements for alignment of "long" reads, for example. So if the data actually comes in as `BYTE|BYTE|LONG` packed together, it may be possible to convince the compiler to pack the data structure in this way, only to have the processor crash on access to the "two-byte aligned" long value.

In other words: Casting of data structures on top of data that isn't the length expected can lead to all manner of problems, without the compiler saying anything.